# Mvc Application, windows authentication, authorization, visibility

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a windows authentication MVC app that needs the username to do a lookup to determine if links are visible and set authorization. Note: I do visibility/Authorization with roles as well.

I need the username so I am currently doing it in OnAuthentification (not sure if this is the right place). I am splicing the username down to put it on the main page and say welcome, User. (presentation purposes)

```
[Authorize]
public abstract class ApplicationController : Controller
{
    public static bool IsApprover;

    protected override void OnAuthentication(AuthenticationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthentication(filterContext);

        if (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true)
        {
            string userName = User.Identity.Name.Remove(0, 16).Replace('.', ' ').ToLower();
            HttpContext.Application["UserName"] = TitleCase(userName, "Nothing");

            //Initialize Values
            HttpContext.Application["IsApprover"] = false; //used for link visibility
            IsApprover = false; //used for Authorization

            //do db lookup and set IsApprover values
        }
    }
}
```

So, I set the values above. I am not including the entity framework code just to be brief. The above works fine and every controller inherits from ApplicationController.

I also have

```
public class CustomAuthorizationValue : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private bool localIsAllowed;

    public CustomAuthorizationValue(bool isAllowed)
    {
        localIsAllowed = isAllowed;
    }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext.Request.IsLocal)
        {
            var authorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
            if (!authorized)
            {
                // The user is not authorized => no need to go any further
                return false;
            }

            return localIsAllowed;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

For Authorization I use:

```
    [CustomAuthorizationValue(IsApprover)]
    public ActionResult Approve()
    {
        //code
    }
```

For Visibility in Razor I use

```
                    @if((bool)@HttpContext.Current.Application["IsApprover"] == true)
                    {
                        <li><a href="@Url.Action("Approve", "Approve")">Approve (@HttpContext.Current.Application["ApproveCount"])</a></li>
                    }
```

This works fine but I have 2 different variables to use, 
one for visibility (HttpContext.Current.Application["IsApprover"]) 
and 
one for Authorization (IsApprover).

Is there a more elegant solution?

Is there another place to put the code rather than override void OnAuthentication?

Is there a way I can just set 1 variable for visibility and Authorization rather than having 2?

Is this the best practice or am I way off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The above works fine and every controller inherits from
>   ApplicationController.

Hmmmm. You are storing user specific information information in the wrong scope:

```
HttpContext.Application["UserName"] = TitleCase(userName, "Nothing");
HttpContext.Application["IsApprover"] = false;
```

In ASP.NET, the Application scope is shared among ALL users of your website. So you have a concurrency issue here.

You should use the HTTP Context scope instead:

```
HttpContext.Items["UserName"] = TitleCase(userName, "Nothing");
HttpContext.Items["IsApprover"] = false;
```

> Is there a more elegant solution?

You could use a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public bool IsApprover { get; set; }
}
```

and then have a couple of extension methods to work more easily:

```
public static class HttpContextExtensions
{
    private const string MyViewModelKey = "__MyViewModel__";

    public static MyViewModel GetMyViewModel(this HttpContextBase context)
    {
        return (MyViewModel)context.Items[MyViewModelKey];
    }

    public static void SetMyViewModel(this HttpContextBase context, MyViewModel model)
    {
        context.Items[MyViewModelKey] = model;
    }
}
```

and then use those extension methods:

```
if (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    string userName = User.Identity.Name.Remove(0, 16).Replace('.', ' ').ToLower();
    bool isApprover = ... do db lookup and set IsApprover value

    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        UserName = TitleCase(userName, "Nothing"),
        IsApprover = isApprover,
    }
    this.HttpContext.SetMyViewModel(model);
}
```

and in your view:

```
@if(HttpContext.GetMyViewModel().IsApprover)
{
    <li>
        <a href="@Url.Action("Approve", "Approve")">
            Approve (@HttpContext.Current.Application["ApproveCount"])
        </a>
    </li>
}
```

NOTE: In this anchor text once again you seem to be using the Application scope to store user specific information such as `ApproveCount` which we discussed earlier.

> Is this the best practice or am I way off?

Well, I would probably use claims based authentication and store this information (IsApprover, ...) as claims in the current user.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I can't access @HttpContext extension from razor..      @if(HttpContext.GetMyViewModel().IsApprover) doesn't work. Help

Comment: Make sure that you have brought the namespace in which this extension method is declared into scope. You could either add a using clause in your view or add ir more globally to your ~/views/web.config file.

Comment: Works Thanks! Added reference to ~/views/web.config file but I called it as                         @if (HttpContextExtensionHelper.GetMyViewModel(this.Context).IsApprover)
                        {
  //code
                        }

Comment: Cool Answer, the only thing I disagree with you on is HttpContext.Application vs HttpContext.Items. You are probably right saying I should use Items instead of Application, but I didn't have concurrency issues. Application.Current is different for each user, I know for sure because I'm storing the usernames and displaying them.